# What would the state function be if the thermodynamic variables didn't depend on each others?

Tags: thermodynamics

A state function is a scalar, vector, or tensor entity defined *univocally* as a function of the thermodynamic variables for a given system. It is a property whose value doesn't depend on the path taken to reach that specific value.

The definition is taken from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eL2U3P7-CoI&list=PLp-8j6_XqvKQcI3w1QXKaxM6whld1O_yy&index=12)

By that definition, we assume that there is a relation between the thermodynamic variables that are properties of particles in the thermodynamic system. Do all properties have to depend on each others?

Comment: "Do all properties have to depend on each others?" I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Properties taken alone, such as temperature, pressure and volume, are independent thermodynamic properties. On the other hand, at equilibrium they are related to each other by an appropriate equation of state.

Comment: Also, since you can't expect us to watch a video, what thermodynamic state functions are vectors or a  "tensor entity"?

Answer (score -1):

Yes all the thermodynamic variables are related to one another.
**Ex- Hydrostatic system**

The first law of thermodynamics is
$dU=TdS+\sum_iF_idx_i$
For a hydrostatic system, $x_1=V$ and $F_1=-P$
$dU=TdS-PdV\tag{1}$
As U(internal energy) is a state function, so it is an exact differential,
$U=U(x_1, x_2)$
So, $dU=A_1dx_1+A_2dx_2\tag{2}$ where $\frac{\partial A_1}{\partial x_2}=\frac{\partial A_2}{\partial x_1}$
From (1) and (2),
$U$ is a function of S and V,
where $\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}=T$ and $\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}=-P$
and $\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}=-\frac{P}{\partial S}$
Also P is a function of V as $P(V)=\frac{RT}{V}$
So we can see that all the thermodynamic variables (properties of the system) are interrelated to each other.

Yes, in short the variation of generalized coordinates are related through first law of thermodynamics and variation in generalized forces are related through Gibbs Duhem relation (which is a result of homogenity of internal energy)